# How to improve this aggregate with many $projects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have created an aggregate function and I feel it's pretty long and non-DRY. I'm wondering what ways I can improve it.

My `Thread` model has a sub-document called `revisions`. The function tries to get the most recent revision that has the `status` of `APPROVED`.

Here is the full model.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56dc750769faa2393a8eb656"),
  "slug": "my-thread",
  "title": "my-thread",
  "created": 1457249482555.0,
  "user": ObjectId("56d70a491128bb612c6c9220"),
  "revisions": [
    {
      "body": "This is the body!",
      "status": "APPROVED",
      "_id": ObjectId("56dc750769faa2393a8eb657"),
      "comments": [

      ],
      "title": "my-thread"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the aggregate function I want to improve.

```
Thread.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    slug: thread
  } },
  { $project: {
    user: '$user',
    created: '$created',
    slug: '$slug',
    revisions: {
      $filter: {
        input: '$revisions',
        as: 'revision',
        cond: { $eq: [ '$$revision.status', 'APPROVED' ] }
      }
    }
  } },
  { $sort: { 'revisions.created': -1 } },
  { $project: {
    user: '$user',
    created: '$created',
    slug: '$slug',
    revisions: { $slice: ["$revisions", 0, 1] }
  } },
  { $unwind: '$revisions'},
  { $project: {
    body: '$revisions.body',
    title: '$revisions.title',
    user: '$user',
    slug: '$slug',
    created: '$created'
  }}
])
```

Comment: Just a note that `"revisions.created"` appears to be missing from your sample document. I've also covered why the `$sort` stage in there is not doing what you seem to think it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot really since there are [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stages in between on purpose. It's also basically "wrong", since the `$sort` cannot re-order the array until you `$unwind` it first.

Then it is better to use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) instead, to just get the first element from the sort in each document:

```js
Thread.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "slug": thread
  } },
  { "$project": {
    "user": 1,
    "created": 1,
    "slug": 1,
    "revisions": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$revisions",
        "as": "revision",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$revision.status", "APPROVED" ] }
      }
    }
  } },
  // Cannot sort until you $unwind
  { "$unwind": "$revisions" },

  // Now that will sort the elements
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "revisions.created": -1 } },

  // And just grab the $first boundary for everything
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "body": { "$first": "$revisions.body" },
    "title": { "$first": "$revisions.title" },
    "user": { "$first": "$user" },
    "slug": { "$first": "$slug" },
    "created": { "$first": "$created" }
  }}
])
```

You could always reform the array with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) and then apply [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) instead of the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to yield just a single element, but it's kind of superflous considering it would need another `$project` after the `$group` in the first place.

So even though there are "some" operations you can do without using `$unwind`, unfortunately "sorting" the arrays generated out of functions like `$filter` is not something that can be presently done, until you `$unwind` the array first.

---

If you didn't "need" the `$sort` on the `"revisions.created"` ( notably missing from your sample document ) then you can instead just use normal projection instead:

```js
Thread.find(
    { "slug": slug, "revisions.status": "APPROVED" },
    { "revisions.$": 1 },
)
```

Only when sorting array elements would you need anything else, since the `$` positional operator will just return the first matched element anyway.